# visual studio 2017 .net core 2.2 in target framework not available

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio, .net-framework, visual-studio-2017

**visual studio 2017 .net core 2.2 in target framework .net not available** 
i use Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 Version 15.9.11

[image]

[image]

Comment: What Visual Studio build are you running?  Edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 Version 15.9.11

Comment: All vital information should be contained in the question not a comment